# (Algorithmic) Differentiation capable Finite Volume Software: Generation Jacobian

Tags: finite-volume, software-recommendation

I am looking for Finite Volume Software that employs a method-of-lines like approach by constructing from the hyperbolic PDE of form
$$\partial_t \boldsymbol u(t,\boldsymbol x) + \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol f\big(\boldsymbol u(t,\boldsymbol x)\big) = \boldsymbol 0 \tag{1} $$
the semidiscretized ODE
$$ \frac{d }{d t} \boldsymbol U(t) =  \boldsymbol F\big(\boldsymbol U(t)\big) \tag{2} \label{2} $$
and allows the computation of the Jacobian of the RHS of \eqref{2}:

$$ J(\boldsymbol u) = \nabla_{\boldsymbol u} \boldsymbol F (\boldsymbol u) $$

Preferably, this is done with algorithmic/automatic differentiation, although finite differences should also be alright for the beginning.
Also, computation for the initial value $\boldsymbol u_0$ would also suffice here.

I checked standard software like [Clawpack](http://www.clawpack.org/) and [FiPy](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/) but they do not seem to offer such capabilities.

Comment: If DG is an acceptable substitute then I can recommend things but I don't know anything for finite volume :/

Comment: @Daniel Shapero Does your recommendation supports polynomial degrees $P=0$? Could be accepted as an answer.

Comment: I am particularly NOT asking for DG - although zero'th order polynomials would be a starting point

Comment: have you checked out DifferentialEquations.jl for this?

Comment: Well as far as I know they just provide some ODE solvers, not a software for PDE solving

Comment: https://github.com/SciML/MethodOfLines.jl has PDE support in progress, but you also can always hand convert the system. It's not yet ideal for PDE's but it will give you AD for free.

Comment: I was not aware of this, that's cool - however, that is only finite difference. There is a [deprecated PDE package](https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqPDEBase.jl), though.

Comment: MethodOfLines.jl does WENO schemes.

Comment: Really? In that case it might be a good idea to update the Readme :)